# Is it illogical (or even abusive) to vote to close my own question?

Tags: discussion

I recently [asked a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104129/better-phrase-for-not-throwing-good-money-after-bad/104136#104136) in good faith, but upon reflection (and after reading comments) decided it was poorly asked.  However, it had already received several (high quality) answers and could not be deleted.

So instead I initiated a vote to close (which was quickly supported by 4 others).

Is this okay?  I'm not poking fun at the site's mechanics or mocking the rules, but it seemed the logical course in my situation.

Comment: If the problem is that the question is "poorly asked", why not perform an edit and improve it? That way, you can leave the question on the table, but fix what you perceive is the root problem.

Comment: Is this a non-meta ELU question? If so then the answer is 'perverse'.

Comment: @J.R. I knew the question was poorly asked, but I didn't know how to improve it.  Fortunately I got several excellent answers before my question was closed (by me).

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, this could apply equally well in any meta forum; I asked here only because the motivating question occurred on ELU.SE.  Maybe I should vote to close this question?

Comment: @Fixee: I think Mitch was answering "what is a good word for the action of closing your own question?", which would be an ELU question, not a meta-ELU question.

Comment: Been there done that. Voted my own questions couple times, especially as duplicates.

Comment: It's perfectly logical.  Especially when you remember that some posters return to the site when they are sober.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is OK. You should always vote your conscience here.

You can also flag your own questions and answers to bring them to a mod's attention if you need help deleting or if you don't have the reputation to vote to close it.

Answer (score 6):

To me it seems self-evident that it's okay. Closing a question can be a good idea no matter who asked it. I consider it thoughtful and responsible to assess your own questions and vote to close if that seems right to you.